# String methods: charAt(Character c) and contains

Tags: java, string, arraylist, methods

Can anyone explain how the String.contains() method work in a string?

```
    String s = "Hello World";
    char c = 'o' ;

    s.contains(c); //This is invalid
    s.contains(Character.toString(c));  //This is valid
```

From what i understand String is an array of characters. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must at least specify the programming language in tags.

Answer (score 0):

I explain in java

The charAt(int pos) method return the perticular character of given position.

And contains(String s) method return boolean value if given string is match to your comparing string then return true otherwise false

**example**

```
String hobby = "Programming";
char c = hobby.cahrAt(3) //Return 'g'
boolean isAvailable= hobby.contains("ing"); // Return true because given string is match with variable
```